# Flask loop not iterating as expected in Bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: python, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I am trying to create a series of dropdown buttons where the dropdown buttons are populated by the dictionary keys and the dropdown items are populated from the lists associated with each key.

The goal is to send a dictionary to a html template and create all of the buttons based on the dictionary contents. The dropdowns will then redirect to whatever location is selected.

The loop in the HTML below will work the first time I run it, but after that all of the dropdown items are set to the last list in the dictionary.

Python code;

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
names = {'Star Wars': ['Luke', 'Han', 'Chewie'], 'Avengers': ['Iron Man', 'Hulk', 'Spiderman']}

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    return render_template('indexdrop.html', names=names)

app.run(debug = True)
```

HTML;

....header omitted...

```
<div class = "jumbotron">
<div class="btn-group">
    {% for idx in names.keys() %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> {{ idx }}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">{{ idx }}</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        {% for item in names[idx] %}
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ item }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Screenshot of Incorrect dropdown:
[image]

Comment: Please share your screen shot. on my side working well every time

Comment: In most of the Flask tutorials and posts, they talk about using a virtual environment, but I haven't seen a good explanation of why you should use a venv. In this scenario I am not, and cannot use a venv. Our IT group blocks all of the dll's and exe's in the venv folder. Could this be part ofthe issue? Does Flask save some data somewhere that may be affecting this dropdown?

Comment: I think, your result is working well. what is your problem?

Comment: Well, the avengers should be Iron Man, Hulk, and Spiderman. In this case, I get Luke, Han and Chewie in both dropwdowns...

Comment: I found solution, and I answered.

Comment: Though this is more of a bootstrap question, Flask uses [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) for html templates. Please add the tag Jinja or Jinja2 to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `<div class="btn-group">` div should be part of your for loop. Currently, you are having a single `btn-group` which has a two `dropdown-menu` divs in it.

The toggle button on second dropdown is looking for the `dropdown-menu` div within the parent `btn-group` (which is, a div with Star wars characters).

```
{% for idx in names.keys() %}
    <div class="btn-group">
        ...
        ...
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Huh, I feel like I tried that and the loop was writing over the first button, but it works for me now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    {% for idx in names.keys() %}
    <div class="btn-group">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> {{ idx }}</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">{{ idx }}</span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            {% for item in names[idx] %}
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ item }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Please use `<div class="btn-group">` every `dropdown group`.

From https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/,
I can find `aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"`, also tried, but same result.

So, I added `<div class="btn-group">` to each `dropdown group`

---

This problem is relative `bootstrap`, not `python, flask`.